# Button hover image not working in CSS

Tags: css, image, button, hover

In my css I am using different image for hover state button but when I hover over the image, there is no change. Can you help find the fix?

```
.button {
background-image:url('/images/search.png');
width:73px;
height:23px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
border:none;
}

.button:hover {
background-image:url('/images/search_active.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
border:none;
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is an abnomality in your absolute path. Try to use `images/` or if it's in a parent folder going down into image `../images/`.

Comment: @Rocket-Singh Have you specified the !DOCTYPE at the beginning of your file and what browser are you using?

Comment: I just double check the path name it's fine. It's only the hover state image that doesn't get displayed. Thanks

Comment: Not sure how but without changing anything it has started working. Thanks

Comment: @RocketSingh are you sure you didn't change anything in comparison to the above displayed code?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your image is in './images/search_active.png' and it is a correct path.